# Hiding scrollbars in Safari (iOS 11.1.2) still not possible with webkit-scrollbar?

Tags: css, safari, webkit, scrollbar, ios11

I need to **hide all scrollbars** in my web application in the latest **Safari** **(iOS 11.1.2)**.
They must be hidden even by scrolling.

Scrollable elements have -webkit-overflow-scrolling set to 'touch' in order to make reading of long lists and content comfortable.

To hide scrollbars, I tried to apply the following rules to scrollable elements:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

or

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

or the combination of it. But it had no effect.

Is it possible to hide scrollbars under this conditions?

Or the only way is to hide the scrollbars using the known hack by giving a negative margin-right value to element's container?

Comment: _“Scrollable elements have -webkit-overflow-scrolling set to 'touch' in order to make reading of long lists and content comfortable.”_ - having to scroll stuff in multiple places is usually not “comfortable”, it is annoying ...

Comment: In my case, stuff can be scrolled in one place on the screen. E.g. it can be message list or a big form. By 'comfortable' i meant the following: if the content is really long, so user can scroll a big part of it up or down by only one gesture, if -webkit-overflow-scrolling set to 'touch'. Because content will continue scrolling for some time after gesture ends. Otherwise, scrolling stops immediately after the user stops touching the screen. That's what it meant.

Comment: So why do you need to hide the scrollbar then, doesn’t that automatically show only _while_ scrolling to begin with?

Comment: It's exactly the task given to me - to do so that scrollbars would be always hidden, even while scrolling.

Answer (score -6):

Maybe You can use:

```
.element {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This prevents scrolling.